# angular.js: Typescript class constructor "this is undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make a simple TypeScript class, however when it's instantiated I receive an `this is undefined` error in the constructor.

**Class:**

```
class MyClass {
    stuff: string;
    constructor(){
        this.stuff = 'stuff';
    }
}
app.config([MyClass]);
```

**Gets compiled into:**

```
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.stuff = 'stuff';
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
app_module_1.app.config([MyClass]);
```

Why is this not working? Why is `this` undefined? This seems to be the appropriate syntax based on examples and other code I've written.

**The remainder of my code (this works):**

```
export let app = angular.module('timeApp', [
    uirouter
]);

class MainController{
    stuff: string;
    constructor(){
        this.stuff = "TESTING";
    }
}

app.controller('mainController', MainController);
```

Comment: It isn't undefined. You're doing something weird in your app.Config function or somewhere else that you haven't shown in the question. The code you have shown couldn't cause this error because it doesn't instantiate the class

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's why I'm so confused. The only other code I have is a main controller in another file that the exact same as the above, save for a different class name. And it works fine.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yeah, I removed the injectables for the test because my fleshed our route class wasn't working due to the `this` error.

Comment: you need to use a function. Not a class. Angular isn't going to use the injector to instantiate your class like it would with a Service registration because that's not how it processes config blocks. Also nothing about TypeScript suggests that you should use classes at all, so I have no idea why you're writing your code this way.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Okay, I'll take note of that. I used this because that is what the examples I've seen of ui-router + typescript show. However, will that affect the aforementioned error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160550/discussion-between-douglas-gaskell-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: no need for a chat, just write a config function. The function will not use `this`. Why would you need it anyway? If you need to capture some state, which would be weird in a config function, your function is a closure.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm clarifying your classes comment, as official code examples use classes. The entire point of Typescript is static typing and intellisense, which using classes provides?

Comment: static typing and intellisense are 100% orthogonal to classes in typescript. You must learn the language. That is all I can say. I recommend you watch one of the many presentations by Anders Hejlsberg, the designer of the language, on Channel 9

Comment: This is why I wanted to separate this to chat, because your statement contradicts the actual documentation, and I'm wondering why... you can see an example on the typescript website yourself for the intellisense gained by defining your own types https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html I'm coming from a C# background on this, if maybe that helps...

Comment: I have a C# background myself. You're misinterpreting the website. The problem is that you are assuming that types imply classes. Classes are a feature of JavaScript. TypeScript types them like it does all other features of JavaScript.

Comment: Seriously, just watch Anders Hejlsburg's presentations on typescript it's available on Channel 9 just Google it. There's a little bit of marketing speech on the website about classes but that's because at the time the language was introduced, es2015 was yet unratified. Es2015 classes are the bases for TypeScript classes. Going a bit further, if you think that strong typing in typescript requires the use of classes you will write awful typescript code. It will be absolutely terrible and confusing. Use classes where appropriate, for example they make sense for Angular JS controllers.

Comment: I see. I was using classes for the intellisense gained from their properties and functions, intellisense I don't seem to get with normal functions. I suppose what confused me more is the use of classes in Angular 2+, and I'm trying to rewrite a classic AngularJS app in Typescript to get a feel for TS. Watching that now, thanks.

Comment: I've written many angularjs apps in typescript long before angular 2 existed. Angular 2 is absolutely the worst way to learn typescript hands down. Frankly Ward Bell doesn't understand the language well and he suggests many awful practices. Furthermore, the reason to angular 2 is so class heavy is that it is obsessed with decorators and decorators only work for classes. Why do decorators only work for classe? because that's how they're specified in JavaScript. I repeat, do not learn typescript by looking at angular you will be confused. For example they `type Type = Function`. WTF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this not working?

Because you are using `app.config([MyClass]);` Angular will call it without `new` and hence `this` will be undefined

## Fix

Don't use classes with angular `config`. Use functions.

## More

- `new` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new